# Button click event in one row effects other rows in listview in android

Tags: android, android-listview

I am having deliver button in every row of listview.when we click on deliver button,background image  should be change for that particular row item(image change to deliver done image).Here I am able to change background image by writing code as setBackgroundResource.but the problem is it will effect to the other row items in listview that means when I am scrolling,other button images for their particular row items are also changed.I have tried for this issue from last three days but no use.Please give me suggestion for doing this.

```
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

          ![enter image description here][1]
            final ViewHolder holder;
           holder = new ViewHolder();


           if (convertView == null) {
               LayoutInflater vi = getLayoutInflater();
           convertView = vi.inflate(R.layout.ambassdor_orders_list_fields, null);
           }

           Routes rou=RouteList.get(position);

           holder.route = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.deliverBtn);
           holder.memberName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.memberNameTxt);
           holder.amount = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.amountTxt);

           holder.memberName.setText(rou.getMemberName());
           holder.amount.setText(rou.getAmount());

           holder.route.setTag(position);
           holder.memberName.setTag(position);
           holder.amount.setTag(position);

           convertView.setTag(holder);

           holder.route.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {

                holder.route.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.done);                          

            }
            });
           convertView.setTag(R.id.routeButtton, holder.route);
           convertView.setTag(R.id.memberNameTxt, holder.memberName);
           convertView.setTag(R.id.amountTxt, holder.amount);
           return convertView;
     }
```

Comment: pls follow this http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidListView/article.htmlto make sure that you are writing code which ensures list view recycling properly

Comment: this url shows nothing to display..404 not found..

Comment: check this http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidListView/article.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

                final ViewHolder holder;
                holder = new ViewHolder();


               if (convertView == null) {
                   LayoutInflater vi = getLayoutInflater();
                   convertView = vi.inflate(R.layout.ambassdor_orders_list_fields, null);

                   convertView.setTag(holder);

               } else {
                   holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
               }

               Routes rou=RouteList.get(position);

               holder.route = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.deliverBtn);
               holder.memberName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.memberNameTxt);
               holder.amount = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.amountTxt);

               holder.memberName.setText(rou.getMemberName());
               holder.amount.setText(rou.getAmount());

               holder.route.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {                  public void onClick(View v) {                                  
                          holder.route.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.done);                          

                }
                });
               return convertView;
         }
```

According to your code you should keep a field to denote the status of the route button background in the model data itself (Routes). so that add code to toggle background with this status.

When you click on button just update the status(eg. rou.setDone(true))

in your **getView** you can add the following code to update this

```
if(rou.getDone()) {
//setBackground
} else {
//revert background
}
notifyDatasetChanged()
```

Comment: pls check the updates in my answer. when u scroll down. the same view u just changed will be reused. so u will see the duplicates. to avoid that u shud keep the button status in model

Comment: please see this image url  http://s592.photobucket.com/user/bhagavan123/media/iOS%20Simulator%20Screen%20Shot%2010-Jun-2015%201.58.58%20pm_zpspjeerpzp.png.html

Comment: Can you please explain how to  keeping status of button event and how can i  set background image for that button when it is set to true..I am little bit confused....

Comment: ** I got, up to some extent with your code snippet,the particular button background image only  updating when scrolling but not when click event**

Comment: ` if(rou.isDone()) {
          //setBackground
          holder.route.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.deliver_done);

          } else {
          //revert background
           holder.route.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.deliver_not_done);
          }
          notifyDataSetChanged();
            
            

           holder.route.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
             rou.setDone(true);
            
            }
            });`

Answer (score 0):

**here is my code**

```
 if(rou.isDone()) {
         //setBackground
            holder.route.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.deliver_done);

         } else {
         //revert background
             holder.route.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.deliver_not_done);
         }
         notifyDataSetChanged();



       holder.route.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            rou.setDone(true);

        }
        });
```

Comment: image is changing when scrolling but  not immediately...what is the problem with this code..

Answer (score 0):

*my problem was solved by changing this line*

```
 if(rou.isDone()) {
     //setBackground
        holder.route.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.deliver_done);

     } else {
     //revert background
         holder.route.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.deliver_not_done);
     }




   holder.route.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        rou.setDone(true);
        notifyDataSetChanged();

    }
    });
```